# Tool to add items and sub-menus to the desktop context menu in Windows

Tags: windows, desktop-environment

I need a program that can add items to the desktop context menu (Right-Click) in Windows. If possible, I need it to be able to create sub-menus to the context menu, because I want to add many items. I'm using Windows 10

I've found this program - [Right Click Context Menu Adder](https://www.askvg.com/right-click-context-menu-adder-free-utility-to-add-program-shortcut-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/) - but I can not create sub-menus with it.

An open source program would be best - that would remove the fear of getting some adware or crippleware or nagware or worse

Comment: Did you contact the author or that program?

Comment: @Mawg - no of, course, I was thinking maybe there are another programs like that

Comment: If you don't get an answer, email him & suggest that new feature. Most developers welcome such suggestions to help improve their apps (I know that I do).

Answer (score 1):

- MenuTools can be a choice for you. It admit severan options. Here is [the link](https://github.com/xCONFLiCTiONx/MenuTools).
- Also [FileMenu Tools](https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/filemenutools) can be usefull:

[image]